# Receive PubNub subscribe message and insert MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pubnub

I'm trying to develop a small system with a easy architecture. In this case I have one simulator that generate random data and publish this data on PubNub. Otherwise, i have too two subscribers: one web based dashboard and MongoDB database.

At this moment, I developed the simulator and the dashboard. The next stage is receive the PubNub subscribe data and insert into MongoDB.

My issue is how I can do this remotely? What is the framework that I should use? I saw many tutorials that start MongoDB DB by terminal on local machine, remotely how this works?

Someone can give me a full explication?

Regards,

Note: I use PubNub JS SDK, my dashboard was developed in HTML, CSS and JS

Comment: What do you mean by remotely? On a server where the MongoDB is? If so, then you just need to write code and deploy it that server that does the subscribe.

Comment: Remotely because I have my Dashboard into web server. I would like to pass the MongoDB database to my own web server that I have already.

With the characteristics that I gave, how I can or the framework that I should use to develop this part? 

I'm newbe on this web systems architectures and I don't know how I do this. Literally, need someone that explain me this concepts.

Comment: Explaining how to implement code on a web server (best practices would be an app server) are a bit out of scope for this forum. If you know how to implement application code on your web or app server then you simple subscribe to the channel using whatever language you whatever language you choose for your server side app (Node, Python, PHP, Ruby, etc).